# I Can't get the value of my angular variable

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have a request ajax that build a repeater angular, and i have a event

html:

```html
<md-button ng-if="item[2].enderecoGlgMaps !== null" class="md-icon-button" ng-click="GeraMapa('{{item[2].nomeSlug}}');" aria-label="Localizacao-Button">
                                                    <img src="<%= ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("URL").ToString() %>/img/icones/icone-localizacao.png" alt="Localizacao {{item[2].nome}}" class="ng-scope">
                                                    <md-tooltip md-theme="default" md-visible="false" md-direction="top">Localização</md-tooltip>
                                                </md-button>
```

angular:

```html
$scope.GeraMapa = function (teste) {
                MensagemAlerta($mdDialog, "Erro", "Seu Navegador não suporta a Geocalização " + teste, "Ok");
            }
```

when click in this event occurrence this message:

"Seu Navegador não suporta a Geocalização {{item[2].nomeSlug}}"

and in element html The value of the right variable show and not the name.

Help me (as in: Any help would be appreciated!)

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

`ng-click="GeraMapa('{{item[2].nomeSlug}}');"`
to this:

`ng-click="GeraMapa(item[2].nomeSlug);"`

Probably this will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the '{{ and }}' surrounding the value you want to send to the method:

```
GeraMapa('{{item[2].nomeSlug}}');
```

There is no need to interpolate the value as you are using an angular directive to make a call to a method.  Also by adding the single quotes you are sending the string literal '{{item[2].nomeSlug}}', which is not what you want.